# Vectorized version of finding the maximum positive value or else the minimum negative value

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame called `purity_list` as follows:

```
In[]: purity_list
Out[]: 
     48    49    50
2   0.1   0.9   0.3
A   0.2  -0.5  -0.6
4   0.3   0.8   0.9
```

I would like to compare this to another numpy array and get the maximum +ve value and if there are no +ve values, I want the lowest -ve value.

So let's say I am comparing this to a numpy array called `purities` as follows:

```
In[]: purities
Out[]: 
array([-0.2, 0.2, -0.8])
```

The closest vectorized code I have right now is this:

```
purity_list = np.where(np.absolute(purity_list) > np.absolute(purities), 
                       purity_list, purities)
```

When I run that code, here is what I will get:

```
In[]: purity_list
Out[]: 
     48    49    50
2  -0.2   0.9  -0.8
A  -0.2  -0.5  -0.8
4   0.3   0.8   0.9
```

What I am really looking for is something slightly different. I have the non-vectorized logic here:

```
for i, v1 in enumerate(purity_list):
    for j, v2 in enumerate(v1):
        if v2 > 0 or purities[j] > 0:
            purity_list.iloc[i, j] = np.max(purity_list.iloc[i, j], purities[j])
        else:
            purity_list.iloc[i, j] = np.min(purity_list.iloc[i, j], purities[j])
```

The result for this is going to be:

```
In[]: purity_list
Out[]: 
     48    49    50
2   0.1   0.9   0.3
A   0.2   0.2  -0.8
4   0.3   0.8   0.9
```

This is the result I am looking for. I am repeating this statement over 100,000 times and my arrays are really large so I need a vectorized version. Performance is the key here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic isn't quite right in your version of `np.where`. Consider what happens when there is a negative value of greater magnitude than a positive value it is compared with. The choice of tool, though, is sound. So all you need to do is correct the condition to better match what you're aiming for:

```
np.where((purity_list < 0) & (purities < 0),
         np.where(purity_list < purities, purity_list, purities),
         np.where(purity_list > purities, purity_list, purities))
Out[42]:
array([[ 0.1,  0.9,  0.3],
       [ 0.2,  0.2, -0.8],
       [ 0.3,  0.8,  0.9]])
```

If nesting `np.where` feels silly, the logic can be combined:

```
np.where(((purity_list < 0) & (purities < 0) & (purity_list < purities))
         |(((purity_list > 0) | (purities > 0)) & (purity_list > purities)),
         purity_list, purities)
Out[43]:
array([[ 0.1,  0.9,  0.3],
       [ 0.2,  0.2, -0.8],
       [ 0.3,  0.8,  0.9]])
```

though I find it clearer the first way.

Comment: Great solution. I tested both your versions and it works for all other cases as well that I haven't shown in my question. I prepared a condition of my own as well, that works: `~(((np.sign(purity_list) + np.sign(purities)) >= np.zeros((1, len(purities)))) ^ (purity_list > purities))`. I think this is right as well, but let me know if it isn't.

Comment: Looks right to me, though you can simplify a little. `np.zeros((1, len(purities)))` can be replaced with a simple `0`, and if you reverse the `>` in the latter clause, or switch `purity_list` and `purities` in the other arguments, you can get rid of the negation (because you don't care which gets picked when `purity_list` and `purities` are the same, and you can absorb negations into one clause with an xor), for a cleaner conditional: `((np.sign(purity_list) + np.sign(purities)) >= 0) ^ (purity_list < purities)`.